# CSS Menu Render issues after updating Google Chrome (v.28)

Tags: css, google-chrome, web, rendering, frontend

Experiencing a huge problem since updating to Google Chrome v.28.

Bug happens when; Hovering over CSS Menu / Links / Buttons or Highlighting text.

Causes; A transparent block to be cut out of the page so that text disappears to show background colour / graphic.

Has anyone else seen anything like this? It's totally buggered a project.
Does Chrome v28 render differently than previous versions. Everything was fine before updating.

Example:

[image: Problem image]

-

Comment: v28 use a new core Blink instead of WebKit, but it should be almost indentical at this stage.

Comment: Show the relevant code, the CSS styles, etc.

Answer (score 0):

See if there's any @-webkit-keyframes or any @-webkit stuff in the CSS.  If there is, move it *all* to the very bottom of the CSS.  On my site, all of the CSS below the @-webkit-keyframes wasn't working properly.
Also if you can post code snippets that would be great.

SO mods:  I would've posted this as a comment, but I'm either unable to (at my current privilege level), or I'm totally not seeing the comment link.  Apologies